# Sending data to a JSON with AS3

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I've asked my client to share his database login and password but he can't give me full access to his database (security reason I suppose). 
He told me to use a REST/JSON service that allows to post the data via this url with a specific key that allows him to identify all the datas coming from my app.

Here's what I did :

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("the_url_using JSON service");
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

 var urlvars: URLVariables = new URLVariables;
urlvars.observer_name = "Test Coco";
urlvars.observation_number = "5433";

trace("urlvars = "+urlvars);

urlRequest.data = urlvars;

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

It's working, as it's sending the data, but the data format seems to be incorrect..

the url returns this error : "Observer name is Missing"

And the "`trace (urlvars)`" output :

```
urlvars = observer%5Fname=Test%20Coco&observation%5Fnumber=5433
```

So I think the problem come from the special character or something like that (as you can "`observer_name`" results by "`observer%5Fname`" and we can see a lot of %5")

Any idea how can I solve this ?

Comment: The problem is unclear. **JSON** is a data format. You cannot send anything **to** it. Furthermore, there's nothing **JSON**-related in your code. **URLVariables** sends its data in a form of url-encoded string (the one you trace, it's correct), it is not **JSON** string.

Comment: The url I'm using in urlRequest use a JSON Service. I'll edit my post with more details.

Comment: Good. Then, still, your code does not have anything JSON-related. REST/JSON service probably means you should send JSON string like '**{"observer_name":"Test Coco","observation_number":5433}**' as a raw POST data.

Comment: Thanks. sorry but first time using a JSON string. Could you show me how to write it ? Something like  `var str:String;` and `str=  "observer_name":"Test Coco","observation_number":"5433"` then `urlRequest.data = str;`  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON string is a string representation of a generic object. Basically you go:

```
var anObject:Object =
{
    "observer_name": "Test Coco",
    "observation_number": 5433
};
```

or you can construct it

```
var anObject:Object = new Object;

anObject['observer_name'] = "Test Coco";
anObject['observation_number'] = 5433;
```

and then you convert it to **String** and attach to request

```
var jsonString:String = JSON.stringify(anObject);

urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = jsonString;
```

Read more about it: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html

Keep in mind that I don't know the specifics of that REST server of yours and the code above just **might** not work as it is. I only explain how to send a JSON string as a POST request.